# Selendroid - Unable to automate twitter app

Tags: android, selendroid

I am new to selendroid. I was able to automate the test app provided in selendroid.io website. Then I tried to automate the twitter app using the com.twiter.andriod.apk. When I start the selendroid server the hub (`http://localhost:5555/wd/hub/status`) shows the "app id" and "base package" but the "mainActivity" is not listed.  When  the test is run I could see the twitter app getting installed into the emulator however it's not getting launched for the test to continue. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that is related to a bug inside selendroid with regards to the Windows support. Just now selendroid-0.6.0 has been [released](https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/releases/tag/0.6.0) and there the bug is fixed.

Comment: {"status":0,"value":{"supportedApps":[{"appId":"com.twitter.android:5.0.1","basePackage":"com.twitter.android"}],"os":{"arch":"amd64","name":"Windows 7","version":"6.1"},"build":{"browserName":"selendroid","version":"0.6.0"},"supportedDevices":[{"screenSize":"480x800","emulator":true,"androidTarget":"ANDROID18","avdName":"My_AVD_1"}]}}

Comment: you should run: aapt dump badging twitter.apk If you have found out the main activity you can open it via: driver.get("and-activity://com.your.path.to.activity")